# How to interpret this summary output in R?

Tags: r

How Do I interpret this summary output in R?

Coefficients:

```
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
国家          3.976e-05  2.484e-05   1.600    0.109    
就业情况     -2.471e-02  2.878e-03  -8.588  < 2e-16 ***
工作类型      1.677e-02  1.700e-03   9.865  < 2e-16 ***
家庭经济地位 -5.482e-02  5.610e-03  -9.772  < 2e-16 ***
性别          4.753e-01  1.223e-02  38.876  < 2e-16 ***
社会阶级      2.292e-02  5.172e-03   4.432 9.34e-06 ***
受教育水平    9.215e-02  2.599e-03  35.461  < 2e-16 ***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
summary(regressor) #or whatever your model is named.
```

- **estimate** contains the estimate of each feature.
- **std. Error** is standard deviation divided by the square root of the sample size that can be achieved via some packages or by manual computations.
- **z value** also comes as t value is the division of estimate by std.err.

$z-value = \frac{Estimate}{std. err}$

- **p-value** $Pr( >|z|) $ indicates the statistical significance. the lower it is for a feature, the more impact the corresponding independent variable would have on the output (dependent variable) here for instance, those features with the p-value equal to $2e-16$ are highly statistically significant. Meaning, their impact on determining the outcome is high.
- the $***$ shows the significance rate of your features (国家, 就业情况, ...).You can have between 0 to three stars and 3 stars depict a high statistical significance.

All of these are practical in analyzing different features.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is helpful. There is another graph which I can't understand. Could you please explain it for me?Threshold coefficients:
      Estimate Std. Error z value
-5|-2 -8.16252    0.35507 -22.988
-2|-1 -4.32096    0.06145 -70.320
-1|1  -2.29177    0.03811 -60.129
1|2   -0.70362    0.03448 -20.405
2|3    0.26781    0.03413   7.847
3|4    2.15511    0.03493  61.696  Could you please tell me what the "-5|-2" probably mean?

Comment: You're welcome. Could you add this graph in the bottom of your first question?

Comment: Sorry,I don't know how to combine the two graph together. I want to send a screenshot to you, but I fail. The second graph is behind the first graph in R.I just divided them when I asked the questions. Sorry, my English is poor. I afraid I can't express myself clearly.

Comment: I think an screenshot would be helpful